# Comparing text box text with listbox items text in vb.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, text, textbox, listbox

how to Compare text box text with listbox items text in vb.NET....Please HELP

Comment: What have you tried so far that didn't work and you would like to ask about?

Comment: i put complete asp.net page code and code behind below and it worked fine, hope this is helpful

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim text As String = Me.TxtName.Text
For Each item As Object In Me.ListBox1.Items
    If item.ToString = text Then
        'Do something'
    Else
        'Do something else'
    End If
Next
```

If you use custom objects as Datasource of your Listbox, override [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring%28VS.71%29.aspx) in the Class to compare them with your Textbox' Text.
[ListBox.ObjectCollection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.aspx)

For example:

```
Class FooClass
    Private _name As String

    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _name = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Me.Name
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

i tried the following in VB.net
it worked fine

the aspx page

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

```
</div>
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>zero</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>first</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>second</asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</form>
```

the code behind

```
Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each item In ListBox1.Items
        If item.ToString = TextBox1.Text Then
            Response.Write("matching " + item.ToString)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim tempInt = lbTeams.Items.Count - 1
While (tempInt > -1)
    If (lbTeams.GetItemText(lbTeams.Items.Item(tempInt)).ToString().Equals(txtTeamName.Text) = True) Then
       MsgBox("Team Already Exist")
       Exit Sub
   End If
   tempInt -= 1
End While
```