# Get ListBox and TextBox Matching Values VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, textbox, listbox, vb.net-2010

I have a listbox1 containing some values

```
value 1
value 2
value 3
value 4
value 5
```

and TextBox1 containing some lines

```
Value 3
Value 5
Value 10
Value 14
```

I want to get values matching in listbox1 and TextBox1
 like

```
Value 3
Value 5
```

and perform some action code if values matches and loop until last value match

I have used this code but its not giving accurate output.

```
Dim compare As String
Dim comparear() As String
Dim list As String
Dim listar() As String

compare = TextBox1.Text
comparear = compare.Split(vbNewLine)
list = TextBox2.Text
listar = list.Split(vbNewLine)
For i = 0 To comparear.Length - 1
    For p = 0 To listar.Length - 1
        If listar(p).Contains(comparear(i)) Then
            txt_match.Text = txt_match.Text & listar(p) & vbNewLine
        Else
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Please try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375148/comparing-text-box-text-with-listbox-items-text-in-vb-net

Comment: I take it your matches are not case sensitive?

Comment: No, Not a case sensitive

Comment: Ok, what have you done so we can further help you. Please show us an attempt.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Look My code, its not giving accurate output.

Comment: Your code compare 2 textboxes. Not a listbox and textbox as you state in your question.

Comment: @AliAhmad thank you for the update, others can now help you with your issue.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes - Can we compare two list boxes ??

Answer (score 1):

You can write

```
Dim result = listBox1.Items.OfType(Of String).Intersect(textBox1.Lines)
```

result is of type `IEnumerable(Of String)`. I.e., you can use it in For Each or add `.ToList` or  `.ToArray` to get a collection.

Note that the match is case sensitive. If you want to ignore the case, you can write

```
Dim result = listBox1.Items.OfType(Of String) _
    .Intersect(textBox1.Lines, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Since the ListBox Items are returned as Objects, I used `listBox1.Items.OfType(Of String)` to convert them to Strings.

---

As I can see in the code example that you have added, you are comparing the lines of 2 TextBoxes and joning the result into a 3rd one, You can do it with these 2 code lines

```
Dim result = textBox1.Lines.Intersect(textBox2.Lines, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
txt_match.Text = String.Join(vbNewLine, result)
```

---

If you wanted to compare the items of 2 ListBoxes

```
Dim r = listBox1.Items.OfType(Of String) _
    .Intersect(listBox2.Items.OfType(Of String), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

`Intersect` works with any two enumerations or collections of the same type

```
A.Intersect(B)
```

returns a `IEnumerable(Of T)` where both `A` and `B` are themselves `IEnumerable(Of T)`. So it does not matter whether you are using the lines of a `TextBox`, the `Items` of a `ListBox` casted to `T` or arrays or `List(Of T)` or anything else.

---

Your code does not work because of 2 different errors:

- You have `Option Strict Off`. This hides an error showing you that you are calling the wrong overload of `Split`. VB tries to convert `vbNewLine` (which is a String) to a Char, and calls `Split` with the 1st char found in `vbNewLine`. Use `Option Strict On` in your project and you will get a compile error. Write this instead

```
comparear = compare.Split(New String() {vbNewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
listar = list.Split(New String() {vbNewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

- Your match is case sensitive. Instead compare like this

```
If listar(p).ToLowerInvariant = comparear(i).ToLowerInvariant Then
```

Comment: @downvoter, please comment. This code creates the set intersection of the values in the listbox and textbox, i.e., it returns the common or matching values as requested in the question.

Comment: You are providing code based on what exactly, if the OP posted their solution (code) then it would give us something to go on. Currently you are providing a "possible" solution that may or may not *address* the users problem. So how does this help the OP?

Comment: The OP said that he has text in a listbox and a textbox whose items/lines he wants to compare and a provided an appropriate answer for this. If you think the question is bad, then downvote the question, not the answers.

Comment: You're missing the point. You provided an answer without the OP even posting the code in question, how could you possibly tell the OP where they are wrong if the OP  didn't post the code? According to your statement above, `Your code compare 2 textboxes. Not a listbox and textbox as you state in your question` this even further validates my statements. IMHO, I would have clarified and asked the OP to post their code, not throw an answer out.

Comment: Well, now he posted his code and I showed solutions for textbox/listbox, textbox/textbox and listbox/listbox.

Comment: vbNewLine is not a string!

Comment: @preciousbetine From Microsoft documentation "Public Const vbNewLine As String " This is obsolete but it is most definitely a string.

Comment: `vbNewLine` depends on the OS. For Windows `vbNewLine  = vbCrLf`.